# sharing using facebook with laravel

Tags: laravel

I am creating task shared with facebook I done it but i failed to add my route in following links of facebook.

HTML:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=YourPageLink.com&display=popup"> Facebbok </a>
```

In stead of Yourpagelink.com i want to insert this

Controller route:

```
`{{route('property-list-details',strtolower($propertydetails->property_slug))}}`
```

how can concate this route in facebook url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried like that?

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{route('property-list-details',strtolower($propertydetails->property_slug))}}&display=popup"> Facebbok </a>`

Comment: how can do like for wastup share?